# A bunch of unrelated wordpress using same memcached don't store correctly their datas

Tags: cache

Before begin I've to warn the reader: watch out the **d**!

On a **single web server** (CentOS 6.3) using php-5.3.3 I've a bunch of **unrelated** wordpress sites (3.5), each one has its own DB (Mysql5.1) so the table_prefix is the same ("wp_").

To speep-up the wordpress I think to APC for the code and a memcache backend for the data, so on my web server I've compile & install libmemcached-1.0.15 and (using "pecl install") php-pecl-memcached 2.1.0 (pay attention to the ending "**d**"). As wp-plugin I used "[memcached redux](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/memcached-redux/)".

On two different servers (CentOS 6.3) I've compiled & installed memcached-1.4.15 backend daemon.

**The Issue**

First I login on *wp.first-domain.com* and everything is fine. When I try to log on on *wp.second-domain.net* I found myself redirect on *wp.first-domain.com*!

If I clean the memcached cache I can login on *wp.second-domain.net*, but then every other wp I try to login redirect me on *wp.second-domain.net*.

In my *wp-config.php* I use these settings:

```
// server list definition
$GLOBALS['memcached_servers']=
      array("memcache1.internal:11211","memcache2.internal:11211",);


// try to add a server-related prefix

$GLOBALS['blog_id']=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
ini_set('memcached.sess_prefix','memc.sess.key.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'.');
```

**IMHO the wp don't store the data with a significant prefix/salt so one blog fetch onother blog datas!**

**The work around**

As workaround I've intalled the wp-plugin "[Memcached Object Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/memcached/)", that uses php-pecl-memcache (2.2.7) (note the missing "**d**") and the following code in config:

```
define( 'WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

I think that I miss some set-up of memcached-redux but I don't exclude a missing functionality (or a bug).

**ADD**

Final goal is to use php-pecl-memcached, so my work around can be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If WordPress is using APC it will use it for its object cache, and since APC is per machine, not per cluster, the two will diverge, giving you problems if you're trying to run 1 site off of two machines.

In that scenario you will want 1 memcached deamon running, and configure your 2 servers to use the 1 instance.

But you mentioned 2 servers with unrelated sites.

So in this case, we have the same issue as here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/many-wp-installations-on-the-same-server

The plugin author says:

> By default it should. **But that requires that you use unique table
>   prefixes (They all cannot be wp_).**
>
> To use it on many sites where the table prefixes are the same, you can
>   add a constant to wp-config.php called WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT, such as:
>
> define('WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', md5(DB_NAME . **FILE**));
>
> md5(DB_NAME . **FILE**) can be replaced by whatever you want, just as
>   long as it is unique per site.

So in effect, you've already stumbled upon the solution for memcache, and the cause.

So perhaps, if you rename your table prefixes so that they're unique, memcached will work

To ellaborate, if we look at the memcachedredux plugins key method:

```
function key( $key, $group ) {  
    if ( empty( $group ) )
        $group = 'default';

    if ( false !== array_search( $group, $this->global_groups ) )
        $prefix = $this->global_prefix;
    else
        $prefix = $this->blog_prefix;

    return preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', "$prefix$group:$key" );
}
```

and later in the constructor:

```
    global $blog_id, $table_prefix;
    $this->global_prefix = '';
    $this->blog_prefix = '';
    if ( function_exists( 'is_multisite' ) ) {
        $this->global_prefix = ( is_multisite() || defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE' ) && defined( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE' ) ) ? '' : $table_prefix;
        $this->blog_prefix = ( is_multisite() ? $blog_id : $table_prefix ) . ':';
    }
```

Here we see that either the prefix is '' or it's the blog ID or the table prefix.

As such there is no handling of multiple sites -> 1 memcached. So change your table prefixes, test if it works. If it does not, then you will need to modify the plugin

Comment: My goal is to use the **php-pecl-memcached** extension, but memcached wp-plugin use **php-pecl-memcache**, so I miss my goal.

Comment: About APC, I did't install any plugin to use APC backend, so WP is not aware of it's presence and can't use it to store date (IMHO).

Comment: see modified answer, I was referring more to the unique table prefixes, clarified